# sort stack of string and return order

Tags: javascript

Here is the question:
Turtles would like to create a pyramid, where every turtle in the pile can only be on top of a larger turtle. The only move they can make is crawling out and then crawling on top. Since they're having a problem achieving this configuration, they ask you to write a program that can tell them in which order to move. You have to advise them, so that it takes the least amount of moves to rearrange.

There are N turtles, represented by their size as numbers in the interval [1, N] (1 and N included). For example: N=3 means there are 3 turtles, and their sizes are: 1, 2, 3.

The "BMC_TEST_INPUT_MAGIC" (with quotes) in the code will be replaced with the actual value of the input. The input is the current turtle stack from top to bottom, one turtle per line. The program has to output the names of whom need to move in order. First name printed will move first.

Sample input:

```
5
1
3
2
4
```

Sample output:

```
4
3
2
1
```

At first I tried to solve it by :

```
var input="BMC_TEST_INPUT_MAGIC".split("\n").sort().reverse()
var res=input.slice(0,input.length-2).join("\n")
console.log(res)
```

Then I get a error "object don't have slice method". Why a string input becomes object after sort()? what's the right way to solve this?

Then I tried to modify it:

```
var input="BMC_TEST_INPUT_MAGIC".split("\n").sort().reverse()
var res=Array.prototype.slice.call(input,1,input.length).join("\n")
console.log(res)
```

It passes simple test "5\n4\n3\n\2\n1"but fails at larger input.

---

There is no error, but it fails addition tests which I don't know the inputs.
I can see other people's solutions that pass the tests though.

```
var input = "BMC_TEST_INPUT_MAGIC".split('\n').map(function(i){ 
return parseInt(i,10);
});
//var input = [ 4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 10,11,12,13, 2, 5, 3 ];
var max=0;
// Find max value thats not on position - starting 'turtle'
for(var i=1;i<input.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<i;j++){
     if((input[i] < input[j]) && (input[i] > max)){ max = input[i]; };
  }
}

for(var i=max;i>0;i--){
    console.log(i);
}
```

In one test, my solution outputs:
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

However his solution outputs:
6
5
4
3
2
1

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? How does it fail? Does it give you errors? or just not the output you expected? Give an example input that "fails", the output you get from it (if any) and what you expected.

Comment: That's strange. `sort` returns an array. And `"51324".split('').sort().reverse().slice` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a string. This string gets split into an array of string (based on new line). Javascript's default sorting behavior of an array of string is alphabetical. Alphabetically speaking the string "10" comes before the string "2". So you need to pass a handler function to the sort function numerically.

```
function handler(a, b) {
    return b - a;
}
```

and call the sort function with this handler function as an argument

```
var input = "BMC_TEST_INPUT_MAGIC".split("\n").sort(handler);
```

Note that the way I wrote the handler function you no longer need to reverse the array.

I also highly recommend ending statements with semicolons (;).

Comment: No need to use slow `parseInt` (and be aware it can be problematic without radix). Just let them be coerced into numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing the bug! I corrected the sort method:) Is "coerced into numbers" means using Number("BMC_TEST_INPUT_MAGIC")?

Comment: Yes, coerce is just another word for convert. Since subtraction is not defined for strings javascript is smart enough to convert the strings to numbers before applying the operation. The original code i converted `a` and `b` to numbers before subtracting which was unnecessary.

Comment: @LoganMurphy That helps, but I'm still trying to figure out why it failed other tests. I added more to qestion